Unexpected behavior when running LAMMPS from Python
I am trying to run a series of LAMMPS input files to parameterize a system, and then using the residuals to optimize the Force Field parameters. I am able to generate the input files and run them using my script which is attached below.
import sys
import subprocess
import resource
import time
import os 
import nlopt

import scipy.optimize
import math
import numpy
import typing

import pandas

# helper functions
def createParameters(keys: typing.List[str], values: typing.List[float]) -> typing.Dict[str, str]:
    currentSet  =   {}
    for key, value in zip(keys, paramVector_1):
        currentSet[key] =   value
    return currentSet

# Initial parameters
paramVector_1   =   [   23.8239,  222.2696,  15.8096, 673.5521, 
                       -31.1295,  -16.6255,  26.8294,  16.0370, 
                      1779.9059,    0.4126,   6.6646,   5.0304, 
                       319.3682,  548.1608, 501.2680, 341.1614, 
                         1.1930,   31.3144, 180.6524,   7.6038,
                         0.8350,   -0.7506,  -0.4747,   2.8207,
                         1.5931,    1.0700,   0.2075,   0.0539,
                         0.0759,    2.0955,   3.4559,   1.2418,
                         3.2600,   80.0000,  70.0000, 235.0000, 
                       154.0000
                     ]

paramVector_2   =   numpy.array(paramVector_1)

keys    =   [   "chi_Al",     "chi_H",      "chi_Na",    "chi_O",
                "ct_AlOH",    "ct_HOH",     "eps_AlO",   "eps_AlOH",
                "eps_HOH",    "eps_NaO",    "eps_OH",    "eps_OO",  
                "eta_Al",     "eta_H",      "eta_Na",    "eta_O",   
                "gamma_Al",   "gamma_H",    "gamma_Na",  "gamma_O",
                "gaussH_Al",  "gaussH_AlO", "gaussH_OH", "gaussR_Al",
                "gaussR_AlO", "gaussR_OH",  "gaussW_Al", "gaussW_AlO",
                "gaussW_OH",  "sigma_AlO",  "sigma_NaO", "sigma_OH",
                "sigma_OO",   "swG_AlO",    "swG_OH",    "swS_AlO",
                "swS_OH" 
            ]


# Training set
training_set    =   [   "gibSEowCNAlAltraj", "gibSEowtraj",        "al6OHtraj",     "al6H2Otraj", 
                              "al6AlAltraj",     "3m1traj",      "d2btod3traj",   "2m1tod2btraj", 
                               "d2tod1traj",   "32wOOtraj",        "32wOHtraj",  "NaOH30wPTtraj", 
                             "m1NaOHPTtraj",     "32wtraj",        "32wPTtraj", "aloh42h2obtraj", 
                               "m1NaOHtraj",    "2m10traj",         "2m1btraj",       "2m1ctraj", 
                            "aloh4scanAlOH",      "d1scan", "aloh4toaloh5scan",    "2m1tod3scan", 
                                       "w2",          "w6",             "d1na",           "d3na", 
                                  "aloh4na",           "w",              "Naw",           "Na5w", 
                                     "NaOH",          "Na",            "wscan",     "al3oh122na", 
                               "al3o3oh6na",    "al3oh9na",          "gibbulk",      "boehmiteb", 
                                   "gib001",   "gib001top",        "gib001bot",         "gib110", 
                                   "gib825"
                    ]

products    =   [   "gibSEowCNAlAltraj", "gibSEowtraj",   "al6OHtraj",       "al6H2Otraj", 
                          "al6AlAltraj",     "3m1traj", "d2btod3traj",     "2m1tod2btraj", 
                          "d2tod1traj",    "32wOOtraj",   "32wOHtraj",    "NaOH30wPTtraj", 
                        "m1NaOHPTtraj",      "32wtraj",   "32wPTtraj",         "2m10traj", 
                            "2m1btraj",     "2m1ctraj",  "m1NaOHtraj",   "aloh42h2obtraj", 
                       "aloh4scanAlOH",        "wscan",      "d1scan", "aloh4toaloh5scan", 
                         "2m1tod3scan",         "d3na",        "d1na",               "w2", 
                                  "w6",         "Na5w",         "Naw",           "gib001", 
                              "gib825",       "gib110"
                ]


reference_data  =   [   53.34110,  -17.5500000000000,   67.59140000,   54.8697,
                        39.29550,  137.9060000000000,    4.60300000,    0.7247,
                        -4.76830,   -4.8418500000000,  -45.92000000,  -93.9900,
                       -24.87000,  -10.6600000000000,  -36.53000000,  -25.1700,
                        14.95700,  206.6600000000000,  -41.36000000, -128.3600,
                       162.92000, -101.9800000000000,   16.02900000,  135.0100,
                        70.98000,  -21.5088000000000,   91.83110000,  -92.7814,
                        28.70340,   24.6990079916871,    2.20880933,    6.1508,
                        17.69662,  224.6836382000000,  -14.64000000,   -9.7900,
                        63.36000,   49.8797000000000,  -36.11500000,  -10.8767,
                        49.04000,   66.5780000000000,  217.33000000,  152.3200,
                       227.86000,  262.4800000000000,  321.90000000,  -27.4000,
                       -86.90000, -204.8128000000000, -224.39676900,   98.4900,  
                       155.90000,  131.1100000000000,  146.29000000,  171.7000,  
                       115.50000,  160.5000000000000,  137.50000000,  170.5000 
                    ]

reference_data_keys =   [      "aloh5",    "aloh4w",          "d1",           "d3",
                                  "d2",    "al2oh6",      "o2h3ts",       "d2ohts",
                             "d2ohts2",        "w2",          "w6",         "Na5w",
                                 "Naw",   "aloh5na",        "d3na",         "d1na",
                          "aloh3wOHTS",     "aloh6",      "NaOH3A",      "NaOH10A",
                             "aloh3w3",   "aloh6na", "gibSE_h2oup", "gibSE_bothup",
                             "aloh3+w", "aloh3wfr4",       "aloh3",       "gib001",
                          "gibbulkOH2",    "gib825",       "gib85",       "gib100",
                              "gib105",    "gib110",     "aloh3w2",   "aloh3wnaoh",
                           "aloh3naoh",       "2m1",       "2m1na",       "d12naw",
                                 "d2b",     "dtrib",    "al3o3oh6",     "al3oh122",
                            "al4o3oh9",   "al6oh18",    "al6oh182",          "OHw",
                                "OH4w",      "2u22",        "3p33",         "NSA5",
                                "NSA4",    "NSA128",      "NSA200",       "NSA300",
                                "NSA1",   "NSAb200",     "NSAb100",      "NSAb500"
                        ]

constraints_data    =   [    1,  2,   2,   2,
                             1,  1,   8,  15,
                            15, 15, 304, 304
                        ]

constraints_data_keys   =   [     "h3oho", "o2h3ts",       "o2h3m",         "Nawc",
                                  "h5o2m", "h5o2ts",  "aloh3wOHTS",        "d2ohm",
                                "d2ohts2", "d2ohts", "gibSE_h2oup", "gibSE_bothup"
                            ]


counter_data    =   [   8,  9,  8, 17,
                        2,  3,  5,  5,
                       12, 19, 19
                    ]

counter_data_keys   =   [          "H3Ow",  "h5o2m", "h5o2ts",             "Na5w",
                                     "Na",   "Nawc",    "Naw", "aloh4toaloh5scan",
                            "2m1tod3scan", "d1scan"
                        ]

pbc_data    =   ["NSA", "gib", "boehmite"]

pressure_data_keys      =   ["gibbulk", "boehmiteb"]

pressure_data_values    =   {  "gibbulk" : [6657, 4512, 4963,  499, 350,  140],
                             "boehmiteb" : [ 110,  105,  112, -672, -10, 2706]
                            }
# Exclusions
charge_exclusion    =   pbc_data + [     "aloh4w", "aloh3wOHTS",          "d2ohts2",  "aloh3w3",
                            "aloh3w2",    "aloh6na", "aloh42h2o_wshell",    "2m1na",
                             "d12naw",        "d2b",         "al3o3oh6",  "al3oh12",
                           "al4o3oh9",    "al6oh18",         "al6oh182", "al3oh9na"
                        ]

xyz_exclusion   =   ["aloh42h2o_wshell"]

dist_exclusion  =   pbc_data + ["Na"]

def clean_slate() -> None:
    os.system("rm -r *log *.err *.frc *.q")

def create_LAMMPS_Input(parameters: typing.Dict[str, str]) -> None:
    filename    =   parameters["filename"]
    with open(f"{filename}.inp", "w") as inputObject:
        # Header section
        inputObject.write("units        real\n")
        inputObject.write("boundary {:<2s}\n".format(parameters["boundaries"]))
        inputObject.write("atom_style   full\n")
        inputObject.write("read_data    {}/{}-q0.data\n".format(parameters["datadir"], parameters["filename"]))
        inputObject.write("\n"*1)

        # Charge section
        inputObject.write("set type 1 charge  1.296\n")
        inputObject.write("set type 2 charge -0.898\n")
        inputObject.write("set type 3 charge  0.449\n")
        inputObject.write("set type 4 charge  1.000\n")
        inputObject.write("\n"*1)

        # Pair style section
        inputObject.write("pair_style hybrid/overlay {} {} sw lj/smooth/linear 5.0 gauss/cut 5.0 \n".format(parameters["coulps"], parameters["coulcut"]))
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff * * {}\n".format(parameters["coulps"]))
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff * * {}\n".format(parameters["coulps"]))
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff * * lj/smooth/linear 0 0 0\n")
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff * * sw param.sw Al O H NULL\n")
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff * * gauss/cut 0 0 1 0\n")
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff 2 2 lj/smooth/linear {}e-2 {}\n".format(parameters["eps_OO"], parameters["sigma_OO"]))
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff 1 2 lj/smooth/linear {}e-2 {}\n".format(parameters["eps_AlO"], parameters["sigma_AlO"]))
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff 2 3 lj/smooth/linear {}e-2 {}\n".format(parameters["eps_OH"], parameters["sigma_OH"]))
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff 2 3 gauss/cut {} {} {} 2.0\n".format(parameters["gaussH_OH"], parameters["gaussR_OH"], parameters["gaussW_OH"]))
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff 1 2 gauss/cut {} {} {} 5.0\n".format(parameters["gaussH_AlO"], parameters["gaussR_AlO"], parameters["gaussW_AlO"]))
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff 1 1 gauss/cut {} {} {} 5.0\n".format(parameters["gaussH_Al"], parameters["gaussR_Al"], parameters["gaussW_Al"]))
        inputObject.write("pair_coeff 2 4 lj/smooth/linear {}e-2 {}\n".format(parameters["eps_NaO"], parameters["sigma_NaO"]))
        inputObject.write("\n"*1)

        # kspace section
        inputObject.write("kspace_style {}\n".format(parameters["kspace"]))
        inputObject.write("\n"*1)

        # thermostat
        inputObject.write("thermo_style custom {}\n".format(parameters["thermostyle"]))
        inputObject.write("thermo 1\n")
        inputObject.write("\n"*1)

        # charge section
        inputObject.write("fix 1 all qeq/point 1 8.5 1.0e-6 200 param.qeq\n")
        inputObject.write("\n"*1)

        # define required groups
        inputObject.write("group constr {}\n".format(parameters["constraint"]))
        inputObject.write("group counter {}\n".format(parameters["counter"]))
        inputObject.write("group fixed union constr counter\n")
        inputObject.write("group todump subtract all counter\n")
        inputObject.write("fix 2 fixed setforce 0.0 0.0 0.0\n")
        inputObject.write("\n"*1)

        # check for conditional arguments
        if parameters["qdump"] == "T":
            print("charge dump active")
            inputObject.write("compute 1 all property/atom q\n")
            inputObject.write("dump 1 todump custom 1 {}.q id c_1\n".format(parameters["filename"]))
            inputObject.write("dump_modify 1 sort id\n")
            inputObject.write("\n"*1)

        if parameters["traj"] == "T":
            inputObject.write("dump 3 todump custom 1 {}.FF.frc id fx fy fz\n".format(parameters["filename"]))
            inputObject.write("dump_modify 3 sort id\n")
            inputObject.write("rerun {}/{}.dump dump x y z box yes\n".format(parameters["datadir"], parameters["filename"]))
            inputObject.write("\n"*1)
        elif (parameters["scan"] == "T") and (parameters["traj"] == "F"):
            inputObject.write("dump 3 todump custom 1 {}.FF.frc id fx fy fz\n".format(parameters["filename"]))
            inputObject.write("dump_modify 3 sort id\n")
            inputObject.write("rerun {}/{}.xyz dump x y z box no format xyz\n".format(parameters["outdir"], parameters["filename"]))
            inputObject.write("\n"*1)
        else:
            inputObject.write("run 0\n");
            print(parameters["supplements"])
            inputObject.write("'print {}: $(pe) $(fnorm) {}' append ener.dat screen no\n".format(parameters["filename"], parameters["supplements"]))
            inputObject.write("\n"*1)

    with open("param.qeq", "w") as paramObject:
        paramObject.write("1 {} {} {}e-2 0 0.0\n".format(parameters["chi_Al"], parameters["eta_Al"], parameters["gamma_Al"]))
        paramObject.write("2 {} {} {}e-2 0 0.0\n".format(parameters["chi_O"], parameters["eta_O"], parameters["gamma_O"]))
        paramObject.write("3 {} {} {}e-2 0 0.0\n".format(parameters["chi_H"], parameters["eta_H"], parameters["gamma_H"]))
        paramObject.write("4 {} {} {}e-2 0 0.0\n".format(parameters["chi_Na"], parameters["eta_Na"], parameters["gamma_Na"]))

    with open("param.sw", "w") as swObject:
        swObject.write("#j  i   k  eps_ijk   sigma_ij  a_ij  lambda_ijk  gamma_ij0.7617  cthet      A  B  p  q  tol\n")
        swObject.write("O   H   H  {}    {}e-2   1     1           {}e-2       {}e-2  0  1  0  0  0.01\n".format(parameters["eps_HOH"],   parameters["swS_OH"],  parameters["swG_OH"],  parameters["ct_HOH"]))
        swObject.write("H   O   O  0     {}e-2   1     0           {}e-2       0      0  1  0  0  0.01\n".format(parameters["swS_OH"],   parameters["swG_OH"]))
        swObject.write("O   Al  H  {}e2  {}e-2   1     1           {}e-2       {}e-2  0  1  0  0  0.01\n".format(parameters["eps_AlOH"], parameters["swS_AlO"], parameters["swG_AlO"], parameters["ct_AlOH"]))
        swObject.write("Al  O   O  0     {}e-2   1     1           {}e-2       0      0  1  0  0  0.01\n".format(parameters["swS_AlO"],  parameters["swG_AlO"]))
        swObject.write("O   Al  Al 0     {}e-2   1     1           {}e-2       0      0  1  0  0  0.01\n".format(parameters["swS_AlO"],  parameters["swG_AlO"]))
        swObject.write("Al  Al  Al 0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("Al  Al  O  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("Al  Al  H  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("Al  O   Al 0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("Al  O   H  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("Al  H   Al 0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("Al  H   O  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("Al  H   H  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("O   Al  O  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("O   O   Al 0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("O   O   O  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("O   O   H  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("O   H   Al 0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("O   H   O  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("H   O   H  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("H   Al  Al 0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("H   Al  H  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("H   Al  O  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("H   O   Al 0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("H   H   Al 0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("H   H   O  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")
        swObject.write("H   H   H  0     0       0     0           0           0      0  0  0  0  0.01\n")

def DDE_RMSE(*args):
    parsed_values   =   [round(arg, 6) for arg in args[0]]

    # Need headers for error calculations
    trajs           =   [item for item in training_set if "traj" in item]
    headers         =   trajs + products + ["q", "E", "f", "fm", "p", "TOT"]
    errors          =   pandas.DataFrame(columns = headers)
    pbc_info        =   pbc_data + trajs

    for system in training_set:
        # Input parameters
        parameters      =   createParameters(keys = keys, values = parsed_values)
        constraints     =   createParameters(keys = constraints_data_keys, values = constraints_data)
        counters        =   createParameters(keys = counter_data_keys, values = counter_data)

        if system in pbc_info:
            boundaries  =   "p p p"
            coulps      =   "coul/long"
            coulcut     =   "8.5"
            kspace      =   "ewald 1.0e-5"
            periodic    =   "XYZ"
            parameters["boundaries"]    =   boundaries
            parameters["coulps"]        =   coulps
            parameters["coulcut"]       =   coulcut
            parameters["kspace"]        =   kspace
            parameters["periodic"]      =   periodic
        else:
            boundaries  =   "f f f"
            coulps      =   "coul/cut"
            coulcut     =   "15.0"
            kspace      =   "none"
            periodic    =   "NONE"
            parameters["boundaries"]    =   boundaries
            parameters["coulps"]        =   coulps
            parameters["coulcut"]       =   coulcut
            parameters["kspace"]        =   kspace
            parameters["periodic"]      =   periodic

        if system.find("scan") != -1:
            spe         =   "T"
            traj        =   "F"
            outdir      =   "./data/scan"
            datadir     =   "./data/data"
            thermostyle =   "pe"
            scan        =   "T"

            # set the parameters
            parameters["spe"]           =   spe
            parameters["traj"]          =   traj
            parameters["outdir"]        =   outdir
            parameters["datadir"]       =   datadir
            parameters["thermostyle"]   =   thermostyle
            parameters["scan"]          =   scan

        elif system.find("traj") != -1:
            spe         =   "T"
            traj        =   "T"
            datadir     =   "./data/traj"
            thermostyle =   "pe"
            scan        =   "F"

            # set the parameters
            parameters["spe"]           =   spe
            parameters["traj"]          =   traj
            parameters["datadir"]       =   datadir
            parameters["thermostyle"]   =   thermostyle
            parameters["scan"]          =   scan

        else:
            scan        =   "F"
            spe         =   "F"
            traj        =   "F"
            datadir     =   "./data/data"
            thermostyle =   "pe fnorm"
            parameters["supplements"] = "empty"
            if system in pressure_data_keys:
                thermostyle =   "pe pxx pyy pzz pxy pxz pyz"
                supplements =   "{} {} {} {} {} {}".format(pressure_data_values[system][0], pressure_data_values[system][1], pressure_data_values[system][2],
                                                           pressure_data_values[system][3], pressure_data_values[system][4], pressure_data_values[system][5]
                                                           )
                parameters["supplements"]   =   supplements

            parameters["spe"]           =   spe
            parameters["traj"]          =   traj
            parameters["datadir"]       =   datadir
            parameters["thermostyle"]   =   thermostyle
            parameters["scan"]          =   scan

        if system in constraints_data_keys:
            constraint  =   "id {}".format(constraints[system])
        else:
            constraint  =   "empty"

        if system in counter_data_keys:
            counter     =   "id {}".format(counters[system])
        else:
            counter     =   "empty"

        if system in charge_exclusion:
            parameters["qdump"] =   "F"
        else:
            parameters["qdump"] =   "T"

        parameters["constraint"]    =   constraint
        parameters["counter"]       =   counter
        parameters["filename"]      =   system

        # create the LAMMPS input file
        create_LAMMPS_Input(parameters)

        commands    =   ["/Users/hemanthharidas/Desktop/Codes/lammps_test/lammps/build/lmp", "-i", "test.inp"]
        outputfile  =   f"{system}.log"
        errorfile   =   f"{system}.err"
        try:
            with open(outputfile, "w") as outputObject, open(errorfile, "w") as errorObject:
                print(f"running {system}")
                subprocess.run(commands, stdout=outputObject, stderr=errorObject, check=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as errorMessage:
            print(errorMessage.output)

        # Now aggregate results
        for system in training_set:
            if system in charge_exclusion:
                xyzfile =   f"./data/xyz/{system}.xyz"
                espfile =   f"./data/esp/{system}.esp"

def main() -> None:
    clean_slate()   # remove files from previous runs
    margin      =   float(sys.argv[1])  # get the margin for fitting from user
    minParams   =   paramVector_2 - (margin * abs(paramVector_2))   # lower bound for parameters
    maxParams   =   paramVector_2 + (margin * abs(paramVector_2))   # upper bound for parameters
    
    # Test run
    DDE_RMSE(paramVector_2)
    quit()

    # first do a global minimization 
    optimizer           =   nlopt.opt(nlopt.G_MLSL_LDS, paramVector_2.size) 
    local_optimizer     =   nlopt.opt(nlopt.LN_SBPLX, paramVector_2.size)
    optimizer.set_local_optimizer(local_optimizer)
    local_optimizer.set_xtol_rel(1e-3)

    optimizer.set_lower_bounds(minParams)
    optimizer.set_upper_bounds(maxParams)
    optimizer.set_min_objective(DDE_RMSE)

    # Now perform the optimization
    optimized_values    =   optimizer.optimize(paramVector_1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


However, I observed that the requested dump files are not getting generated while using this script. On the other hand, if I run the generated input files using a bash script, the input files work as expected, and the requested dump files are generated. This confirms that the input files which are generated from the script are correct, and there is some issue in the way python calls the LAMMPS executable. Any help on troubleshooting this would be much appreciated.
Note: I cannot provide the data files for testing this code since the data is unpublished.
#!/bin/bash

for inp in *.inp
do
#       echo $inp
    outfile=$(awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-4)}' <<< "$inp")
    lmp -i $inp > $outfile.log
done


Could you please do the following: 1. Split the code into two sections one for generating input files and other for writing the dump files. This will help make it easier to debug. 2. Please provide the bash script here.

The dump files are created from the LAMMPS input files, which are generated from the DDE_RMSE function in the code. I have included the bash script in the edit.
